# In a sand castle competition, contestants are allowed to use only water, shovels and $10$ cubic feet of sand.

Tags: geometry

In a sand castle competition, contestants are allowed to use only water, shovels and $10$ cubic feet of sand.  To transport the correct amount of sand, they want to create cylinders that are $18$ inches tall to hold enough sand for one contestant.

a. What should the diameter of the cylinders be? Please round to the nearest whole number: ___________ inches.

b. If you round that diameter to the nearest whole number, how much sand will the canister hold? Please round your answer to the nearest whole number: _________ $\text{ft}^3$.

If it helps anyone I can confirm that $a=3$ and $b=11$ are incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT first convert cubic feet into cubic inches

Comment: What I did to find my first answer was                                                
hπr^2 = V
1.5(ft)πr^2 = 10(ft^3)       
r^2 = 10/1.5π      
r^2 = 2.12206...     
r = 1.456731241     
2r = D     
2.913462482 = D

Comment: @J.Doe.  2.91 ft is fine, but the answer asks for inches.

Comment: @Bram28 I converted 10 cubic feet into 17280 cubic inches and got the answer of 110 inches for a. Can anyone confirm is this is correct?

Comment: does 110 inches equal 2.9 ft?

Comment: @J.Doe  Doesn't seem like it. It's 18 inches tall, so you get $\pi \cdot r^2 \cdot 18 =17280$. Wolfram Alpha says r is about 17.5 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(17280%2F(18*pi))  Oh wait, that's radius. So multiply by 2 to get diameter: about 35 inches diameter

Comment: @Bram28 Yes you're right I forgot to put parenthesis when I plugged it in on my calculator

Comment: @DougM Thank You. So for b I should just plug all the numbers into the formula for Volume and then convert the cubic inches into cubic feet?

Comment: When $d = 35$ inches, the rounding error between the exact value you had before rounding and rounding is very small (less than 0.04 inches).  When you carry it back the other way, the rounding errors should still be small.

Answer (score 0):

A 3 inch diameter cilinder that is 18 inches tall would hold 10 cubic feet of sand?!?  JUst common sense tells you that isn't anywhere close to what you need.

OK! First covert everything to inches.

$1$ cubic feet of sand is $12^3=1728$ cubic inches of sand.

And so $10$ cubic feet is indeed $17280$ cubic inches.

So, to find the radius of the cylinder we need to solve for:

$$\pi \cdot r^2 \cdot 18 = 17280$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(17280%2F(18*pi))) says $r \approx 17.48$ and so rounded off the diameter is $35$ (inches)

The rounding error is so small that for b), the answer is guaranteed to be $10$. Let's see:

We get

$$\frac{18\cdot \pi \cdot (17.5)^2}{1728}$$ cubic feet

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=18*pi*(17.5)%5E2%2F1728) says it's about $10.02$. Yep! $10$ it is.